# How to create 5 columns row in Jupiter theme?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

Is there any way to create 5 equal columns in Jupiter WordPress theme? It has 3 columns, 4 columns, 6 columns, but not 5. How can I do that?

Comment: is it in page builder?

Comment: @charankumar Yes, I guess so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this workaround:
When selecting a columns layout in the row, choose "Enter Custom Layout For Your Row" input field and add the below layout and hit update:

1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 + 1 /6

You'll have 5 columns, but they will be left aligned. To center them, open the first column settings, and switch the tabs to "Width & Responsiveness", then set the offset for three first devices to 1 column.

There is also documentation for Jupiter theme regarding your query:
https://themes.artbees.net/docs/five-columns/
where another method is described. Check it.

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

option 1:

Customize the jupiter theme page builder

option 2:

Its a simple hack

if you are using page builder then you can add 6 column builders, but dont add 6th column,

then you will have 5 columns with empty space for 6th column, then add a custom class like five-column for that column and apply css for it to make it look like 5 column

```
/* 5 Columns */

.five-column {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.five-column {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .five-column {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .five-column {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .five-column {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not sure how to do it exactly with its page builder. Do you have any references?